# Incorporate Enum.GetName(...) into Linq Query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, enums

I have the enumeration:

```
public enum CmdType {
    [Display(Name = "abc")]
    AbcEnumIdentifier = 0,

    [Display(Name = "xyz")]
    XyzEnumIdentifier = 1,
    ...
}
```

I'd like to get the names of each enumeration into my query, but even using `.WithTranslations()` I'm getting this error:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String
>   GetName(System.Type, System.Object)' method, and this method cannot be
>   translated into a store expression.

The query:

```
var joinedRecord =
    (
        from m in mTable
        join b in bTable on m.Id equals b.aRefId
        select new {
            aId = a.Id,
            aAttrib1 = a.Attrib1
            ...
            bCmdType = Enum.GetName(typeof(CmdType), b.CmdType)
        }
    ).WithTranslations();
```

How do I return a generated value using `Enum.GetName(...)` within the query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are calling `Enum.GetName(typeof(CmdType), b.CmdType)` which cannot be translated to SQL as the `Enum` definition is not in the DB if you take a look at your rows you'll see there is an `int` instead of the name of the `Enum` value in question.

Try this:

```
var joinedRecord =
(
    from m in mTable
    join b in bTable on m.Id equals b.aRefId
    select new {
        aId = a.Id,
        aAttrib1 = a.Attrib1
        ...
        bCmdType = b.CmdType
    }
)
.AsEnumerable() // or ToList()
.Select( // map to another type calling Enum.GetName(typeof(CmdType), b.CmdType) )
.WithTranslations();
```

What this does is that by calling `AsEnumerable()` or `ToList()` you are no longer processing an instance of `IQueryable<T>` (which is what your original query returns, on the bad side once you do this all returned objects will be on memory). So once you have objects in memory you can use them just as any other C# object which should allow you to use the methods you want.

Comment: Luiso - a fine example, thank you.  Unfortunately, @lukas-kabrt was just a hair faster with the same code.  +1, however for a great example and explanation.

Comment: Correction: Marking yours as my answer since you responded a heartbeat faster.

Answer (score 6):

LINQ to entities tries to translate your query to SQL and it fails to do so, because there is no equivalent of the `Enum.GetName` method in SQL.

You need to materialize the results of the query and convert the enum values to their name in the memory.

```
var joinedRecords = (
    from m in mTable
        join b in bTable on m.Id equals b.aRefId
        select new {
            aId = a.Id,
            aAttrib1 = a.Attrib1
            ...
            bCmdType = b.CmdType
        }
).AsEnumerable() //Executes the query, further you have simple CLR objects
.Select(o => new {
    aId = o.Id,
    aAttrib1 = o.Attrib1
    ...
    bCmdTypeName = Enum.GetName(typeof(CmdType), o.CmdType)
});
```

Comment: Lukas - thank you!  Your solution and the one from @Luiso are very similar.  Marking yours as my answer since you responded a heartbeat faster.

Comment: Correction: @Luiso came in faster, my apologies.  Thank you for the great example!

Answer (score 2):

Try casting to AsEnumerable() so you can use LINQ to Objects. LINQ to Entities will try to translate it to SQL for which there is no equivalent:

```
var joinedRecord =
    (from m in mTable
    join b in bTable on m.Id equals b.aRefId)
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(x =>  new {
        aId = a.Id,
        aAttrib1 = a.Attrib1
        ...
        bCmdType = Enum.GetName(typeof(CmdType), b.CmdType)
    })
   .WithTranslations();
```

See http://www.lavinski.me/ef-linq-as-emumerable/

Comment: Steve, getting the error (on build) that "a query body must end with a select or a group clause."  This was the issue I was having prior to asking the question here on SO - I wasn't sure WHAT to select when using just the "from m in mTable join b..."  Thank you for the reference link, however!